# mysql-python installation eror

Tags: macos, python-2.7, mysql-python

Keep getting this error while trying to install mysql-python on osx version 10.12.3 and i get the same error even when using virtualenv. installed mysql using brew (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for osx10.12 (x86_64)) and version of setuptools is 18.5

sudo pip install mysql-python

```
 Installing collected packages: mysql-python
Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-ihGRLH/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5ktJF8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer
_mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                         ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                               ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1127:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1129:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1168:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
#define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
#define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1178:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1180:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1274:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
#define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                        ^
_mysql.c:1466:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1468:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1504:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1506:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
        if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
            ~~~ ^ ~
14 warnings generated.
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/include/mysql/my_config.h:172:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_LONG' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIZEOF_LONG      8
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:54:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_LONG             4
                ^
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/include/mysql/my_config.h:177:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_TIME_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIZEOF_TIME_T    8
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:57:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_TIME_T           4
                ^
_mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
        if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
            ~~~ ^ ~
3 warnings generated.
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
 Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,       tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-ihGRLH/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5ktJF8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-ihGRLH/mysql-python/
```

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same error on MacOS.

Solved with the following steps:

Step 1. Make sure you have installed openssl with homebrew.

```
brew install openssl
```

Step 2. In a terminal:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```